# My VBA behaves differently when assigned to a button

Tags: vba, excel

I have set up a Quality Check sheet which needs to store results in a separate sheet called 'Data' as a row of data, and save an archived version of the full Check Sheet in a separate workbook.
I'm quite a novice on VBA but have managed to get what I need working. My problem comes when I assign the macro to a button which is contained on my check sheet. If I press the button it copies the wrong sheet over and basically does not do what it does when I run the macro manually. Can anyone suggest anything please?

Thanks

My code is as follows:

```
Sub SaveForm()

' SaveForm Macro
' Saves form data to the Data Sheet

'Checks for completion of mandatory fields

If IsEmpty(Range("b3").Value) = True Then
  MsgBox "Please complete 'Agent Name' before saving"
  Exit Sub

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("b4").Value) = True Then
  MsgBox "Please complete 'Call ID' before saving"
  Exit Sub

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("b5").Value) = True Then
  MsgBox "Please complete 'Call Length' before saving"
  Exit Sub

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("D3").Value) = True Then
  MsgBox "Please complete 'Business Name' before saving"
  Exit Sub

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("D4").Value) = True Then
  MsgBox "Please complete 'Date of Call' before saving"
  Exit Sub

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("D5").Value) = True Then
  MsgBox "Please complete 'Time of Call' before saving"
  Exit Sub

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("b7").Value) = True Then
  MsgBox "Please complete 'Assessor Name' before saving"
  Exit Sub

ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("b8").Value) = True Then
  MsgBox "Please complete 'Date of Assessment' before saving"
  Exit Sub


End If

'Copies a range contained within the "Checksheet" and pastes
'it into the next available row on the "Data" sheet

'The reason it is in a straight row as opposed to sporadic cell
'references is because I have set the sheet up this way for simplicity

Range("M14:BP14").Copy

Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
Workbooks("Call Feedback Form V0.42.xlsm").Sheets("Checksheet").Activate

Call CopyRenameWorksheet

Workbooks("Call Feedback Form V0.42.xlsm").Sheets("Checksheet").Activate

End Sub
```

.

```
Sub CopyRenameWorksheet()

'This renames the worksheet based on cell references and archives to another workbook

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wh = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
If wh.Range("B3").Value <> "" Then
ActiveSheet.Name = wh.Range("B3").Value & " " & Format(wh.Range("D4").Value, ("yymmdd")) & " " & wh.Range("B4").Value
ActiveSheet.Move After:=Workbooks( _
"Archived Quality Forms.xlsx").Sheets(1)

End If
```

Comment: Some of your code is not properly formatted (not in a grey box) but I'm not sure how it should be. Also, try to supply an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Marein. Sorry I'm totally new to this.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get it all in the grey box, the site formatted it this way. Is there a way to adjust it?

Comment: Also, please could you clarify what you mean by MCVE ?

Comment: I edited your OP for formatting  - when it is peer reviewed itll change

Comment: Is the button on a different sheet than where the copying takes place?

Comment: @RWGFloyd, MCVE means Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example. I included a link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is due to the fact that you are referencing the wrong sheet. Make sure you always fully qualify when you will be using different sheets.

I would start the Subs with

```
dim ws as worksheet
set ws = Worksheets("Sheetname")
```

and then you can change all of the ranges to be like `ws.range("A1")`

This way they will always reference the range on the correct sheet.

I would start by going through your code and making sure that every single reference to a range is referencing a worksheet and a range on said worksheet.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, sorry I should really learn to listen. That worked perfectly! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: No problem, can you mark this as the right answer if you're happy with the answer please? @RWGFloyd

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this line of code

```
Range("M14:BP14").Copy
```

You need to explicitly state what sheet youre referring too. Like i.e.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M14:BP14").Copy
```

Comment: Thanks but this part seems to work okay. The issue is that once it has copied this range to the Data sheet, it then copies the whole Data sheet to the Archive workbook. Stranger still it renames it too without any error. When I step through the code or run it manually I get no issues at all. It's only a problem when initiated via the button.

Comment: wrsphil's comment is correct. The issue is still bad naming references